# ¿Cómo hacer para que un item de un Combo se seleccione con un click?

Tags: javascript, extjs

Agregando un `combo`a mi proyecto en **Ext.js** me tope con el problema de que, hay seleccionar algún ítem de la lista, no lo hace en el primer **Click** que doy, sino que al hacer lo anterior mencionado, solo sobresalta un border punteado sobre el ítem y nada más, sino hasta el segundo click lo escoge y se escode el scroll del `Combo`.

Código del `Combo`:

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    anchor: '100%',
    padding: 10,
    fieldLabel: 'Type',
    name: 'fieldType',
    labelStyle: "font-weight:bold;",
    store: new Ext.data.Store({
        fields: [{
            name: 'description',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'name',
            type: 'string'
        }, {
            name: 'uuid',
            type: 'string'
        }],
        autoLoad: true,
        hideTrigger: true,
        minChars: 1,
        triggerAction: 'query',
        typeAhead: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: "../",
            extraParams: {
                action: "catalog",
                catalog: "fieldtypeoptions",
                params: JSON.stringify({
                    uuidToken: Ext.connectionToken
                })
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'dataTypesList'
            },
            listeners: {
                exception: function(proxy, response, operation, eOpts) {
                    var responseArray = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
                    Ext.Notify.msg(responseArray.message, {
                        layout: "bottomright",
                        delay: 5000,
                        type: "error"
                    });
                }
            },
        }
    }),
    typeAhead: true,
    triggerAction: 'all',
    valueField: 'uuid',
    displayField: 'description',
    listeners: {
        change: function(combo, value) {
            console.log(value);
            console.log(combo);
            console.log(combo.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema?, ¿Será bug del navegador? (estoy usando **Chrome**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema estaba con el `autoload: true`, ya que me hacía `request` 2 veces (no tengo la menor exacta idea de porque) de la misma data, después de haberlo desplegado y tratar de seleccionarlo a la primera.