# No se puede leer la propiedad 'fields' de null

Tags: javascript, extjs

He estado trabajando con **Extjs** desde hace ya unas dos semanas y me he visto bombardeado por varios errores (dado que soy nuevo con este *framework*) Y hoy revisando mi consola, dado que tengo un [problema con un combobox, de un item que se selecciona hasta hacer click sobre él dos veces y no una vez](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6011/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-para-que-un-item-de-un-combo-se-seleccione-con-un-click) (como debería).

El aviso del error dice lo siguiente:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of null`

El cual revisando mi código, está en el siguiente bloque (nótese que haré calcar el área donde exactamente me dice que estaría el posible error):

```
classifyFields: function (field, list) {
        var me = this;
        var type = null;
// el siguiente if, en teoría, es el problema.
        if (field.fields.variableLengthField) {
            type = "variableLenghtField";
        } else if (field.fields.journalSaved) {
            type = "journalField";
        }
        console.log(type, field, list);
        list.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.name == type) {
                me.dataFields.push({
                    "uuidFielMonitorType": item.uuid,
                    "fieldProperties": field.fields
                });
            }
        });
        console.log(me.dataFields);
    }
```

Puede alguien orientarme con esto? digo, para saber si este es realmente el problema que me origina lo del bug con el `Combobox` , está demás agradecerles por la ayuda!

Comment: De donde sacas el método `classifyFields` eso no parece parte de ext.js. si es código de tu aplicación sería bueno que incluyeras mas código para ver de que forma el framework interactúa con la función y así saber como son obtenidos los argumentos de la función.

Answer (score 1):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fields' of null`

**No puede leer la propiedad "fields" porque field tiene un valor Nulo**, revisa que tenga un valor para poder acceder a sus propiedades:

```
  if (field.fields.variableLengthField) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisa que el atributo **fields** de tu función sea diferente de `null`, por ejemplo para evitar que la función continúe si ese parámetro es `null` puedes ejecutar lo siguiente antes de utilizarlo:

```
if (!fields) {
    return;
}
```

De esta forma la función termina si no se ha enviado ese parámetro.